# Changing dimension of a list

Tags: python

`d=[[[1],[1],[1]]]`

There is a list like the one above.

I wanted the list to be `[1,1,1]`.

```
d=[[[1],[1],[1]]]

print(np.shape(d))

d_1=[]

for item in d:

    d_1.extend(item)

print(d_1)

d_2=[]

for item in d_1:

    d_2.extend(item)

print(d_2)

>>>[1,1,1]
```

I did it like this but is there a more simple way?

Comment: How about `np.array(d).flatten()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1):

How About this? You can use recursion, though it may exceed the recursion limit.
In that case:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500) #==== Set any number for the recursion limit
```

Here is the main code

```
d=[[[1],[1],[1]]]
new_l=[]
def check(lists:list):
    for i in lists:
        if not isinstance(i, list): #==== If it is not a list
            new_l.append(i)
            
        else:
            check(i) #=== Again iterate through the list
    return new_l
print(check(d))
```